# file not found exception when reading file from Linux EXTREME VPS

Tags: java, linux, file-read

i am storing images on Linux EXTREME VPS using java

when i store it on server path i'm getting is

```
/var/sentora/hostdata/campusguru/public_html/resources/images/bharath.png
```

reading the path using following code

```
if(imagePath != null && imagePath.length() > 0 )
    {      

        byte fileContent[] = new byte[3000];
        try (FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(new File(imagePath))) {  //here the exception
            while(fin.read(fileContent) >= 0) {
                // Base64.encodeBase64(fileContent);
            }
        } 

        imagePath = imagePath.replace("\\", "/");


        byte[] imageInByte;
        BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath));


        // convert BufferedImage to byte array
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(originalImage, "png", baos);
        baos.flush();
        imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
        baos.close();
        encodedFile = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(imageInByte);

    }         
    stuAdmissionDetails.setStuImg(encodedFile);    
}
```

when i read using above code i am getting following Exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \var\sentora\hostdata\campusguru\public_html\resources\images\bharath.png (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.rasvek.cms.controller.StudentController.getStudentAdmissionByAdmissionId(StudentController.java:696)
    at com.rasvek.cms.controller.StudentController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cb2af793.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at com.rasvek.cms.controller.StudentController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bbc517cf.getStudentAdmissionByAdmissionId(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1100)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:687)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

how to solve this problem?

is there any other way to read file from  linux server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you are using the wrong file path.

You say that you are reading a files on a Linux server, and it seems that you are trying to read them on a Windows machine.  From this I infer that you have mounted the Linux file server on your Windows machine as an SMB file share ... or something like that<sup>1</sup>.

However ... the path that you are using *looks* like a Linux file path:

- The path separator is `/`.
- The path starts with "/var/..." which is a common convention for UNIX / Linux systems.

But if you have remote mounted the Linux file system, the file path that you should use is the file path that you would use from the Windows command prompt.  Probably starting with a drive letter.

(I can't tell you what it should be.  It depends on how you mounted the file system, and how the remote file server *exports* the file tree.)

---

<sup>1 - On the other hand, you may just be using some code you found on the internet which could be completely inappropriate to the task you are trying to do.</sup>

Comment: i meant to ask is there any separate way of reading file from linux server using java  ?

Comment: OP is duplicating the post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51335151/file-not-found-exception-when-reading-file-from-linux-extreme-vps

Comment: There may be other ways, but it depends on what protocols are available to access the remote file system.  And you have not mentioned anything about that in your Question

Comment: I notice that "Linux Extreme VPS" is actually a hosted server offering from a commercial provider.  As such, you could have installed / configured any number of different services for presenting your data, including HTTP / HTTPS, FTP, SFTP, FTPS, SMB, NFS ... and many others. Each will require a different way of accessing the data.